# How do you unlock new gear in the shop?

Tags: splatoon

So I've been playing a bit of online multiplayer, getting some money, and basically buying out everything I could in the shop in order to force the gear (not weapons, their unlock method is explicit) to cycle and hopefully give me some new choices. I'm not sure if leveling up is the main factor that determines getting new gear, or if it just happens when the news broadcasts rotate maps.

Comment: If you play the single player mode, you are able to get blueprints from each boss. You can then bring those blueprints to the shop and get those "Custom" weapons.

Comment: Note: I definitely did not mean weapons (I noted that above), but the clarification is appreciated. However, that leaves a concern: I'm guessing that's how I unlock 2 of each of the weapons. I've seen the "alt" weapons all the way up until level 20, though, so does that mean the blueprints work for multiple new weapons each?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The clothing shops get new gear every day. Your level will determine the availability of 2-3 star items in the shops.

Additionally, beating the single-player campaign will grant you two sets of 3-slot gear. Along the way, as you mentioned, several weapons will also be unlocked for purchase. The best resource I've found for these weapon unlocks is [here](http://www.primagames.com/games/splatoon/tips/how-unlock-every-weapon-splatoon). Anything without a "Single Player Scroll" entry is unlocked exclusively through multiplayer, and made available for purchase at the level indicated in the left column.